# Chrome TCP HTTP connection

Tags: html, google-chrome, http, tcp

Imagine this scenario:

- There is a client on Chrome, **C**
- There is a webserver, **W**
- On the webserver is a html file, **WH**, an image **WI**

**C** wants to visit the webpage on **W**. A TCP connection is opened. The webserver sends **WH** to **C**. **C** sees that there is an image on **WH**, **WI**...

Now the question comes: Does the client establish a new TCP connection to request the image? Or does it simply send a new PSH-ACK?

---

Seconds question: does this differ between browsers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The client requests the image using another HTTP `GET` request. It can either do this on the same connection, or it can open a new connection. If the client starts parsing the page while it's downloading, it will probably use a new connection so the two files can download concurrently. And if it sees more image tags, it can open additional connections for this. To keep from overloading the server, well-behaved browsers have a limit on the number of concurrent connections they'll open to the same server, typically around 4.

If it first downloads the whole **WH**, it can reuse the original connection to request the image. But if there are multiple images, it will probably open separate connections for each (up to the aforementioned limit) so they can be downloaded in parallel.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I discovered that the `Keep-Alive` header will keep the client only open with one connection. Without that header it will open more connections.

Comment: That shouldn't be necessary in TCP/1.1, it's supposed to keep the connection open by default. Are you using TCP/1.0?